# Can I pass sqlite3 table column name as search parameter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

My first help request on Stack Overflow. Python version 3.6.4

I have an issue with my code. It is meant to to return a price quote based on parameters entered - such as country, shipment weight and in what zone is the city in given country.

The table looks like something this(excel picture).
Screenshot [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCoiv.png)
Is it possible to narrow down which column to use. Such as if search parameters are estonia and 3 kgs it nicely returns all three columns of zone1, zone2 and zone3:

```
What country? :estonia
weight?: 70
('estonia', '75', '10,83', '12,25', '14,43')
```

But can I pass in an argument based on user input to narrow down which zone column to use to get the value?

For example if a city is in zone1, take only values from column zone1 based on other search parameters

My robust code is as follows:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

conn = sqlite3.connect("transportHinnakiri.db")
c = conn.cursor()

df = pd.read_csv("baltikum.csv")
df.to_sql("baltikum", conn, if_exists="append", index=False)

input_country = input("What country? :").lower()
input_weight = int(input("Weight?: "))

def weight_category(input_weight):
    if input_weight < 1:
        return 1
    elif 1 < input_weight <= 3:
        return 3
    elif 3 < input_weight <= 10:
        return 10
    elif 10 < input_weight <= 20:
        return 20
    elif 20 < input_weight <= 31.5:
        return 31.5
    elif 31.5 < input_weight <= 50:
        return 50
    elif 50 < input_weight <= 75:
        return 75
    elif 75 < input_weight <= 100:
        return 100

result = weight_category(input_weight)

def get_post():
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM baltikum WHERE country=? AND weight=?",(input_country, result))
    row = c.fetchone()
    return row

result_final = get_post()

print(result_final)`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for but here is how I would do it. First get the city from the user:

```
city = input("input City: ").lower()
```

Then I would create some data structure, say dictionary, that holds all the zones and their cities:

```
zones = {'zone1': ['boston', 'new york'], 'zone2': ['san fransisco', 'los 
angeles']}
```

Then you can have a function that takes in a city and returns a zone

```
def get_zone(city):
    for zone in zones.keys():
        if city in zones[zone]:
            return zone
    return "Error city not found"
```

Of course you would have to do something to normalize user input. Then you could create a command string and execute the command

```
def execute_command(zone, weight, country):
    cmd = "SELECT {zone} FROM baltikum WHERE country={country} AND weight={weight}".format(zone = zone, country = country, weight = weight)
    data = c.execute(cmd)
    return data
```

Then you only get data from selected zone. Hope this helps!